# Access files generated in the backend

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, pythran

I'm a beginner. I started exploring Pythran and Transonic a few days back. I learned that Pythran generates a C++ file from the Python input file. I want to read those C++ generated files in the backend.

Do anyone of you have any idea about accessing files generated in the backend?

I'm implementing Pythran using Transonic's support.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running pythran with the `--help` option?

```
...
optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  -o OUTPUT_FILE       path to generated file. Honors %{ext}.
  -P                   only run the high-level optimizer, do not compile
  -E                   only run the translator, do not compile
...
```

So, the answer is: use the **-E** option

```
pythran my_python_file.py -E
```